# Can I find certain function that satisfy optimization condition?

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

Sorry for my poor description. This is my first post as I have a problem that I'm stuck on. Please note that this problem was created by me, and if it's flawed, it can be fixed.

There exist function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g_1,g_2,\dots g_k:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R,k\in \mathbb N $. Suppose I know $g_k^*$ such that $f\circ g_k^*\ge f\circ g_k, \forall k$.
Can I find what $f$ looks like?

If $f$ and $g$ are polynomials, can I solve the problem? What are the assumptions I need to make to solve the problem? I hope the shape of $f$ to become increasingly clear as $k$ go to infinity.

Additionally, if there is any math that you recommend I do to find the answer to this problem, I would appreciate it.

Let me know if you need a more detailed history of how I came up with this, and I'd be very grateful for the opportunity to explain it to you further.

Comment: You are all correct. I just editted it.

Comment: I think this depends a lot on what constraints, if any, are on $g_i$ and $g_i^*$. For instance if $g_i$ is a constant then the condition about $f \circ g_i$ is almost useless. Similarly if $g_i^* = g_i$. On the other hand a condition like $f(x + 1) \ge f(x)$ could certainly be useful.